# Absolute value's vertical bar symbol in Text cell formula

Tags: formatting

I want to typeset Gielis's *superformula* using the `DisplayFormula` cell style. The result should look like $$\rho = R \left(\varphi \right) \left[ \left| \frac{1}{a} \cos \left( \frac{m}{4} \varphi\right)\right| ^{p_2} + \left| \frac{1}{b} \sin \left( \frac{m}{4} \varphi \right) \right| ^{p_3} \right] ^{{-}\frac{1}{p_1}}$$

If I don't write $p_2$ and $p_3$, the result is quite fine, as

```
\[Rho]=R (\[CurlyPhi])[|1/a cos(m/4 \[CurlyPhi])|+|1/b sin(m/4 \[CurlyPhi])|]^(-(1/Subscript[p, 1]))
```

produces this:
[image: Gielis equation without p2 and p3: everything is fine]

However, if I try to add $p_2$ and $p_3$ to this formula, the result is quite confusing, as the `|` becomes smaller for I don't know what reason:

```
\[Rho]=R (\[CurlyPhi])[|1/a cos(m/4 \[CurlyPhi])(|^Subscript[p, 2])+|1/b sin(m/4 \[CurlyPhi])(|^Subscript[p, 3])]^(-(1/Subscript[p, 1]))
```

[image: Why does the ABS operator get smaller???]

I see that a simple pipe `|` is not what I need to typeset an expression like mine. Which character is the correct one to use in this case?

Comment: The pipe `|` is the infix form of `Aternatives`, so yours is barely correct syntax. Use `Abs` for the absolute value, backets `[` and `]` for function arguments and `Cos` and `Sin` for the cosine and sine function, repectively. Then you can apply `TeXForm` and use the external package [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) to convert to nice formulas for display.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I took MaTeX as a second plan, but if the pipe behaves like that, I'm totally using MaTeX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to type the expression into a cell, use <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of just <kbd>|</kbd> for the left side of the absolute value expression, and similarly <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>|</kbd> for the right side. Here is an animation where I enter your expression into a `Text` cell style:

[image]

If your question is actually about how to create an expression that formats in the way you want, you should clarify this.